# Converting source property value to custom destination value using Automapper in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a

```
Source.foo = 1;
```

and type of

```
Destination.foo
```

is **string**, and i want to choose myself which value to assign to Destination.foo according to the number i get in Source.foo.

Is there is a way i can transform

```
Source.foo = 1 to Destination.foo = "A" 
Source.foo = 2 to Destination.foo = "B"
```

and so on?

Comment: I don't know if automapper supports this case. i guess you need to modify/create a setter/property which accepts an integer. There you could implement the transformation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
.ForMember(x => x.foo, cfg => cfg.MapFrom(x => GetFooValue(x)));
```

And then you can write GetFooValue to return anything you want. As an example:

```
private string GetFooValue(int foo){
    if(foo == 1)
        return "A";
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is the only option that works with ProjectTo. Saved me a lot of frustration. Thank You!